# How do you find using regular expression, characters beginning with and ending with any characters

Tags: regex, unix

In

> AXyz122311Xyslasd22344ssaa Aklsssx@sdddf#4=sadsss kaaAASds

How do we get the characters `"slas"` out that begins with `"11Xy"` and ends with `"d223"` in UNIX using regular expression?

Comment: negative rating is unfair as am not familiar with UNIX,regexp and googling for pattern matching returned no appropriate result with different approaches using grep, awk, expr, sed, cut. Could some one also include simple grep way for regular expression searches in a string in UNIX for this purpose?

Comment: for example, grep returs whole string and not "slas" when echo `$VAR | grep '(?<=11Xy).+(?=d223)'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what [lookahead and lookbehind assertions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) will do.

Have you tried something like this?

`(?<=11Xy).+(?=d223)`

---

*Update*

You can use `grep -o` to display only the matched text in a *nix environment.

Comment: thanks, could you also share the UNIX usage as updated in comments

Comment: echo $MSG | grep -o '(?<=11Xy).+(?=d223)' did not work. Cannot grep a variable an year later

Answer (score 0):

Not too late, but, downvoters need to include that *NIX grep has a few limitations and lookaround/lookbehind/etc., do not actually work on most versions.

http://www.regular-expressions.info/grep.html

*Since neither grep nor egrep support any of the special features such as lazy repetition or lookaround,*

Only, recently was it added to GNU grep (3.0 ?) released recently which **basically uses perl compatible regex**

https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/grep.html#The-Backslash-Character-and-Special-Expressions

*-P
--perl-regexp    Interpret the pattern as a Perl-compatible regular expression (PCRE). This is highly experimental, particularly when combined with the -z (--null-data) option, and ‘grep -P’ may warn of unimplemented features.*

On **upgrading my grep and using -P**, it works like a charm

```
$cat test.txt | ggrep -oP '(?<=11Xy)(.*?)(?=d223)'
slas

$ggrep --version
ggrep (GNU grep) 3.1
Packaged by Homebrew
Copyright (C) 2017 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
...
```

On some OS, especially mac, your grep is BSD, so you have install GNU grep using homebrew to use it.

```
$grep -V
grep (BSD grep) 2.5.1-FreeBSD
$brew install grep
...
$ggrep -V
```